# How do I use Node.js clusters with my simple Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, express, cluster-computing

— I built a simple app that pulls in data (50 items) from a Redis DB and throws it up at localhost. I did an ApacheBench (c = 100, n = 50000) and I'm getting a semi-decent 150 requests/sec on a dual-core T2080 @ 1.73GHz (my 6 y.o laptop), but the proc usage is very disappointing as shown:
[image]

Only one core is used, which is as per design in Node, but I think I can nearly double my requests/sec to ~300, maybe even more, if I can use Node.js clusters. I fiddled around quite a bit but I haven't been able to figure out how to put the [code given here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) for use with my app which is listed below:

```
var 
    express = require( 'express' ),
    app     = express.createServer(),
    redis   = require( 'redis' ).createClient();

app.configure( function() {
    app.set( 'view options', { layout: false } );
    app.set( 'view engine', 'jade' );
    app.set( 'views', __dirname + '/views' );
    app.use( express.bodyParser() );
} );

function log( what ) { console.log( what ); }

app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    redis.lrange( 'items', 0, 50, function( err, items ) {
            if( err ) { log( err ); } else {
                res.render( 'index', { items: items } );
            }
    });
});

app.listen( 8080 );
```

I also want to emphasize that the app is I/O intensive (not CPU-intensive, which would've made something like [threads-a-gogo](http://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) a better choice than clusters).

Would love some help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually, your workload is not really I/O bound: it is CPU bound due to the cost of jade-based dynamic page generation. I cannot guess the complexity of your jade template, but even with simple templates, generating HTML pages is expensive.

For my tests I used this template:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Example
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container
      ul#users
        each user in items
          li User:#{user}
```

I added 100 dummy strings to the items key in Redis.

On my box, I get 475 req/s with node.js CPU at 100% (which means 50% CPU consumption on this dual core box). Let's replace:

```
res.render( 'index', { items: items } );
```

by:

```
res.send( '<html lang="en"><head><title>Example</title></head><body><h1>Jade - node template engine</h1><div id="container"><ul id="users"><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li><li>User:NOTHING</li></ul></div></body></html>' );
```

Now, the result of the benchmark is close to 2700 req/s. So the bottleneck is clearly due to the formatting of the HTML page.

Using the cluster package in this situation is a good idea, and it is straightforward. The code can be modified as follows:

```
var cluster = require('cluster')

if ( cluster.isMaster ) {
  for ( var i=0; i<2; ++i )
    cluster.fork();
} else {
  var
      express = require( 'express' ),
      app     = express.createServer(),
      redis   = require( 'redis' ).createClient();

  app.configure( function() {
      app.set( 'view options', { layout: false } );
      app.set( 'view engine', 'jade' );
      app.set( 'views', __dirname + '/views' );
      app.use( express.bodyParser() );
  });

  function log( what ) { console.log( what ); }

  app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
      redis.lrange( 'items', 0, 50, function( err, items ) {
            if( err ) { log( err ); } else {
              res.render( 'index', { items: items } );
            }
      });
  });

  app.listen( 8080 );
}
```

Now the result of the benchmark is close to 750 req/s with 100 % CPU consumption (to be compared with the initial 475 req/s).

Comment: wow, thanks!, that worked really well — imgur.com/Cpqy6 — I spent most of yesterday pushing it from 80 to 150 and now a simple if block is making all that work look like peanuts. The note about templates was very educational; I knew there would be some cost but didn't think it'd be "475 to 2700" big. Can I optimize Express? Btw, I also wanted to share the CPU stats — imgur.com/n7WPv — I went as high as 15 workers but both cores never went to 100%. I haven't enabled Redis persistence so it shouldn't touch the disk, but around the 30K-request mark my disk spins crazy. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: With a dual core box, the optimal number of worker processes is 2. I don't know how much memory you have, but if you start too many workers, you may trigger swapping. On my box, one node process takes around 50 MB in memory.

Comment: The performance bottleneck is not express but jade. You could try another templating engine (still working with express). Here is a list: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

Comment: oh no, by "I went as high as 15 workers" — I meant I started at 2, as listed in your answer, & worked my way up through 3, 4, 5 and gave up at 15; none of those configs saw both the cores reach 100% simultaneously, which got me wondering if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: "The performance bottleneck is not express but jade." — whoops, I meant "jade" but said "express". What according to you is faster than Jade?

Comment: " I don't know how much memory you have, but if you start too many workers, you may trigger swapping." — I have 1.5 GB out of which it used up 500 MB with swap around 260 MB out of 3.5 GB. Puzzler.

Comment: Just to close out the discussion on templates, I found this benchmark of different template engines — http://paularmstrong.github.com/node-templates/benchmarks.html, handy for those hitting this question who wish to improve their template performance as well.

Comment: According to my own benchmark, the fastest ones are Swig, nTenjin, thunder and doT in that order.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll check out Swig and will update here if the I get significant improvements over Jade. Thanks again, Didier.

Comment: You should try `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` instead of `node app.js` .